# Mathematics language/syntax/grammar Cheat sheet

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

As the hack fraud mathemagician that I am, I use mathematics typically only in engineering related uses...It is almost always practically applied...and once it gets large (or tedious) enough I am almost always using software to solve different problems. ODE's, PDE's, linear algebra and etc such as mathematica or rarely matlab.

However as of recently, (particularly in writing for others), but also when having to learn a new subject, or sub-sub-subject of a particular field I am often confronted with a wall of new things to read and attempt to understand.

While I surely know many puzzle like solving methods to apply basic mathematical structures/rules to solve a particular equation or apply some method, I find myself always forgetting basic mathematical *syntax*. Often times the problem I have is simply not knowing how to actually *read and correctly understand* a statement written in the mathematics grammar/syntax/symbology more so than the actual use or application of such systems.

Is there a particularly nice 'cheat sheet' of sorts for just mathematics symbols and their syntax/use?

I mean things simply as the correct use of $\setminus$ or $\in$ or the the actual meaning of {}, (), []
or (] used in context, Relationship symbols, or others such as $\Rightarrow$ or more, less frequent symbols such as $\forall$ (for me less frequent that is...as I understand this symbol isn't just shorthand for "for all" and must also be used in a specific way) or $\exists!$

I'm not looking for a cheatsheet on how to write said symbols in LaTeX, nor something like this [websites fairly nice set of mathematics cheatsheets](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/cheat_table.aspx) , but one that says or explains, in english what they mean with context of example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2915899/545671) Is sort of in the direction I'd prefer, though it's more far more in depth, than a simple sort of cheat sheet I'd be prefer to find.

$$a \in R  \setminus\{0\} \text{ Represents a is element of R excluding 0}$$

With a continued list of other meanings and etc.

I'd appreciate if anyone is aware of such a thing, or maybe a tiny syntax handbook (an actual *hand* book, not the incredibly useful but unwieldy 2kg Bronstein mammoth). I would love to become more proficient in mathematics and less hacky in its use, however I certainly need to get up to speed in actually reading it, before that can happen.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this source may help you
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols
Also, this widget allows you to draw a symbol. Once you have identified what the symbol is called, you can search it up to learn more about it. http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html